# Oracle ALTER SESSION for date format and sort option, commit necessary?

Tags: php, oracle

Recently, I am assigned to a legacy project which has Oracle as a database and php as a service layer. There is a DB.php class which handles database execution. It contains a function called connect(), which connects to the database. Inside this connect, apart from spawning a new connection, it also calls two additional function that does something like -

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = <something>
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = <something>
```

The problem is that these two functions are explicitly committing the transactions to the DB right after ALTERing the SESSION. This has a side-effect wherein, any transaction prior to connect will also be committed.

We usually don't commit sql queries until the end of a request, after checking for all validations being right.

Also, in any given call stack there are multiple places where DB.php is instantiated and connect is called. In php, when calling oci_connect with same parameters, it will return the same connection if it already exists. Therefore, in some instances this connect function is committing transactions which are not to be committed.

I have tried to get around this problem but my workarounds are an overkill to the problem. My question really is that, ***Is it necessary to commit after ALTERing SESSIONs in php->oracle?***

Spent an awful lot of time fixing it in other ways and also, I tried looking this up on the internet and didn't really find an answer where this *commit* scenario is taken into consideration. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALTER SESSION ...` does not commit your current transaction implicitly. A COMMIT is not needed to make it effective.

Only when you run `ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL ...` then uncommitted transactions must either be committed or rolled back prior to executing this clause for DML.

The only way to avoid the issue would be to execute the `ALTER SESSION` command right after you opened the connection to database, i.e. before you run any DML statements. This would be the most useful option anyway.

Or you have to use explicit `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` in `TO_CHAR()` calls. For ordering you would have to use `ORDER BY NLS_SORT(..., 'NLS_SORT=...')` (thanks to Radagast81)

Comment: ALTER SESSION commands are already executing right after a database connection is opened. if COMMIT is done implicitly on ALTER SESSION, then do I not have to COMMIT them explicitly? Also, if there is an implicit COMMIT happening in ALTER SESSION, does it also COMMIT all my DML statements which are queued before it?

Comment: You can `order by nls_sort(char, 'NLS_SORT=Binary')` or something like that. And encapsulate the function in an `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` might also be an option.

Comment: @taimuralam, my first answer was wrong (I tested it). Please see my updated answer.

Comment: If you run ALTER SESSION right after connection is opened why do you have any issues with commited data then?

Comment: Like I said, in any given call stack, there are multiple instantiation of DB class and also connect being called right after it. And, oci_connect in php, if called with same parameters, will return the same underlying connection if it exists. So keeping this in mind, there are non-commitable DML statements being executed in some functions and since this oci_connect returns the same connection hence, when ALTER SESSION commit takes place, it will eventually commit all transactions in the present connection. @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: From @Radagast81 comment, I am now thinking of AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION for ALTER SESSIONs, do you think it wise to do so? Are there any implications this might result in?

Comment: Again, the `ALTER SESSION` does not commit anything. If you have issues with unwanted COMMIT then it is executed somewhere else.